# Hibernate with Oracle11g Sequence

Tags: java, hibernate, oracle11g

Hi I use a Oracle 11 with Hibernate and in one of table I use a sequence for generating ID's.

For some reason I see wiered behaviour. I see records inserted later in time have have a lower ID.

I understand some numbers might be missing in ID, but the records created later being assigned those missing ID's is whats messing my logic n requirnment.

Any help on why is this happening would be very helpful.

Thanks

Comment: Are you using Real Application Clusters (RAC)?

Comment: Yes. I am using Oracle RAC.